# Delete URI Segment in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, uri

I want to remove some url in CI

if any echo like:

```
www.blabla.co/content/5DRwA/6Yt54/bla-bla
```

so, replace to:

```
www.blabla.co/content/bla-bla
```

nb: 6Yt54 and 5DRwA is a random value

How I remove URI Segment 2 from behind like that?
How can I solve it?

Comment: The url is generated by your controller?

Comment: Is there any need of these values

Comment: If you could tell us where and how this will be used, you might get the answer you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the uri class. First retrive uri with:

```
$array = $this->uri->segment_array();
```

Then remove second segment:

```
unset($array[2]);
```

Unfortunately your url doesnt seem to follow CI convention (you could use then `$this->uri->assoc_to_uri($array)`). So iterate over array to create uri.

```
$my_uri = ''; //better name it $my_uri not to conflict with $this->uri
foreach ($array as $value) {
$my_uri.= '/'.$value;
}
```

And then you can use your new uri f.e. to redirect:

```
redirect($uri);
```